# How to identify and copy a pane?

Tags: panels

I have a site that is developed with panes. There are "Contact Us" forms at the bottom with bad links. Some pages share the same pane, some have different panes.

My task is to standardize all the pages so that they use the same pane, so that fixing a link in one will fix the link in all of them.

What I see as the title is `Contact Us (id: 1740)`. That's the title of the pane that is shared among certain pages. On other pages, it's `Contact Us (id: 1738)`, with different ids for different pages.

What I would like to do is copy the pane entitled `Contact Us (id:1740)` to all the pages that have the Contact Us section. However, I am not sure how to copy it from one page to another.

When I click on the gear icon of the page and choose `Edit`, I can edit the values, but I don't see what type it is. I've looked at node of nid 1740-- it's not that node. Also, I don't see that title in the list of re-useable panel panes.

How can I copy this panel pane to other pages where it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my pane was a fieldable panel pane. As far as I can tell, these panes serve as templates, and when placed in panels, they are copied into one-off panes.

So my solution was to add another copy of the fieldable panel pane, this time making sure to check the 'reusable' box. Then, I replaced all the one-off panes throughout the site with the reuseable pane.